# Encoding issues on Google Calendar Integration

Tags: php, wordpress, character-encoding, google-calendar-api

I am working on a plugin in Wordpress to integrate events with my Google Calendar. The integration works, but when I use special characters they don't show correctly. Example, "ß" in German becomes "Ã".

I tried to add the following in my code, but it didn't solve it.

```
if ( false === mb_check_encoding($description, 'UTF-8') ) {
    $description = utf8_encode($description);  
}
```

`$description` is the string value I pass to Google Calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using [`iconv`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php), e.g.:

```
iconv(mb_detect_encoding($description, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $description);
```

Comment: Didn't know about `iconv`. It works now. Thank you :)